# How to Eager Load (Two-Level Upward)?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, eager-loading

The models look like this:
Customer (Model)
- Order (Model)
-- Product (Model)
--- Color (Model)
- Name (Property)

When listing the details of Product, I want to show the Name of Customer (Name is a property of the model Customer).

The code I'm using is

```
db.Products.Include("Order").Include("Customer").Include("Color").Where('my where query')
```

The error message I got is that Product doesn't have a navigation property with Customer. How can I get the properties of Product?

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3.1 with SQL Azure backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot notation in `Include`:

```
db.Products.Include("Order.Customer").Include("Color").Where(...)
```